# Difference between War and Warfare

Tags: meaning, grammar

I'm reading The Little Prince and there is a phrase:

> "Is this **warfare** between the sheep and the flowers not important?"

Is it correct to exchange **warfare** for **war**?
When to use **war** instead of **warfare**? Is there a difference?

Comment: Yes, I have to look for the mean but I don't understand. Both war and warfare are nouns. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/warfare - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/war. For me are the same.

Comment: It's nuanced. War is "a state of armed conflict between different nations or states or different groups within a nation or state.". "Warfare" is the engagement and form of war.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***WAR***

> armed fighting between two or more countries or groups, or a particular example of this:

[-Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/war)

***Warfare***

> the *activity* of fighting a war, **often including the weapons and methods that are used**:

[-Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/warfare)

*War* describes ***a state of political affairs*** between 2 or more regions/countries engaging in  armed conflict.

*Warfare* would include  ***the strategy and tactics*** of the opposing forces.